# Source package directories

Tags: linux, open-source, directory

I'm a newbie so please be tolerant. When you download a random open source package you find a directory tree which is similar in every package. It's something like:

```
\
|- doc
|- m4
|- src
|- tests
```

Is this some kind of standard? Where can I find it's specification? Is there any program that generates this tree in your directory for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard for this, let alone a specification; it's just a convention (with many variants). Some packages have the source files directly in the top-level dir, others in `src/`, still others have a directory per component. `tests` might also be called `test`. However, the abbreviations `doc` (documentation) and `src` (source) are quite strongly engrained in Unix developers' collective memory.

(IDEs might make such a directory hierarchy for you, but do realize that many Unix/Linux developers, including yours truly, don't use IDEs at all.)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Yes, this structure is created by</del> No, this structure is just a convention used together with software called [GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) (Autotools in short). It's a set of programs to ease project configuration, compilation, linking and building across different operating systems and environments. Many IDEs and editors support it.

Comment: Which part of the GNU build system makes these directories? I've always did `mkdir` myself when using autotools.

Comment: @larsmans I might actually confused words convention and standard. These directories are automatically created by IDEs and editors, not autotools itself. Everybody can use his own structure, because processes are ruled by Makefiles. Thanks for correction.